# Why is nested field not on top?

Tags: css, html

I'm playing with HTML for the first time and following along with some tutorials.

Now I made a bunch of fields which I called containers and for some reason one of them is apparently put behind one that I think it should be in front of

[image]

Here "Container 5" is highlighted, its backgroundcolor is black... The container 1 is gray and is in front of it as far as I can see.

Why is this? container 5 is inside container 1. I have tried playing around with various settings in the CSS like the `Position` but this did not change anything really.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="layoutexamples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!--CSS = CASCADING STYLE SHEET!-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container1">
        <p>container1 beginning</p>

        <div id="container2">
            <p>container2 beginning</p>
            <div class="static">
                <p>Static</p>   
                <p>static is the default value and renders a box in the normal order of things, as they appear in the HTML.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="static">
                <p>Static</p>   
                <p>static is the default value and renders a box in the normal order of things, as they appear in the HTML.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="static">
                <p>Static</p>   
                <p>static is the default value and renders a box in the normal order of things, as they appear in the HTML.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="static">
                <p>Static</p>   
                <p>static is the default value and renders a box in the normal order of things, as they appear in the HTML.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="static">
                <p>Static</p>   
                <p>static is the default value and renders a box in the normal order of things, as they appear in the HTML.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="relative">
                <p>Relative</p> 
                <p>relative is much like static but the box can be offset from its original position with the properties top, right, bottom and left.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="rel2" class="relative">
                <p>Relative</p> 
                <p>relative is much like static but the box can be offset from its original position with the properties top, right, bottom and left.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="rel3" class="relative">
                <p>Relative</p> 
                <p>relative is much like static but the box can be offset from its original position with the properties top, right, bottom and left.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="rel4" class="relative">
                <p>Relative</p> 
                <p>relative is much like static but the box can be offset from its original position with the properties top, right, bottom and left.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="rel5" class="relative">
                <p>Relative</p> 
                <p>relative is much like static but the box can be offset from its original position with the properties top, right, bottom and left.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="container3">
                <p>container3 beginning</p>
                <div id="container4">
                    <p>container4 beginning</p>
                    <div id="abs1" class="absolute">
                        <p>Absolute</p> 
                        <p>absolute pulls a box out of the normal flow of the HTML and delivers it to a world all of its own. In this crazy little world, the absolute box can be placed anywhere on the page using top, right, bottom and left.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="abs2" class="absolute">
                        <p>Absolute</p> 
                        <p>absolute pulls a box out of the normal flow of the HTML and delivers it to a world all of its own. In this crazy little world, the absolute box can be placed anywhere on the page using top, right, bottom and left.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="abs3" class="absolute">
                        <p>Absolute</p> 
                        <p>absolute pulls a box out of the normal flow of the HTML and delivers it to a world all of its own. In this crazy little world, the absolute box can be placed anywhere on the page using top, right, bottom and left.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="abs4" class="absolute">
                    <p>Absolute</p> 
                    <p>absolute pulls a box out of the normal flow of the HTML and delivers it to a world all of its own. In this crazy little world, the absolute box can be placed anywhere on the page using top, right, bottom and left.</p>
                </div>

                    <p>Height = 600px</p>
                    <p>container4 end</p>
                </div>
                <p>container3 end</p>
            </div>

            <p>container2 end</p>
        </div>

        <div id="container 5">
        <p>Some text</p>
            <div id="float1" class="float">
                <p>Float</p>    
                <p>Floating a box will shift it to the right or left of a line, with surrounding content flowing around it.</p>
                <p>Floating is normally used to shift around smaller chunks within a page, such as pushing a navigation link to the right of a container, but it can also be used with bigger chunks, such as navigation columns.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="float2" class="float">
                <p>Float</p>    
                <p>Floating a box will shift it to the right or left of a line, with surrounding content flowing around it.</p>
                <p>Floating is normally used to shift around smaller chunks within a page, such as pushing a navigation link to the right of a container, but it can also be used with bigger chunks, such as navigation columns.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="float3" class="float">
                <p>Float</p>    
                <p>Floating a box will shift it to the right or left of a line, with surrounding content flowing around it.</p>
                <p>Floating is normally used to shift around smaller chunks within a page, such as pushing a navigation link to the right of a container, but it can also be used with bigger chunks, such as navigation columns.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>container1 end</p>

    </div>

    <div id="fixed">
        <p>Fixed</p>    
        <p>fixed behaves like absolute, but it will absolutely position a box in reference to the browser window as opposed to the web page, so fixed boxes should stay exactly where they are on the screen even when the page is scrolled.</p>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
}

body{
    background: #FD6;
}

#container1{
    width: 900px;
    height: ;
    background-color: grey;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

#container2{
    background-color: #E80;
    position: relative;
    height: ;
    width: ;
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.static{
    width: 300px;
    height: ;
    background-color: #2EE;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: ;
    position: relative;
}


.relative{
    width: 300px;
    height: ;
    background-color: #F86;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: ;
    left: 320px;
    position: relative;
}

.relative#rel2{
    left: 15px;
}

.relative#rel3{
    left: 100px;
}

.relative#rel4{
    left: 600px;
}

.relative#rel5{
    left: 100px;
}

#container3{
    background-color: #D0D;
    position: ;
}

#container4{
    background-color: white;
    height: 600px;
}

.absolute{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #6AF;
    position: absolute;
}

.absolute#abs1 {
    margin-left: 400px;
    border: 2px black dashed;
}

.absolute#abs2{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 400px
}

.absolute#abs3{
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.absolute#abs4{
    margin-left: 800px;
    margin-top: 800px;
}

#container5{
    border: 2px blue solid;
    background-color: black;
    position: ;
}

.float{
    width: 300px;
    height: ;
    background-color: #EF0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: ;
}

.float#float1{
    float: left;
}

.float#float2{
    float: right;
    height: 400px;
}

.float#float3{
    border: 2px black dotted;
    padding: 5px;
    width: auto;
    clear: both;
}

#fixed{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using so much positioning? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thats just trying out different things. Im not trying to make a website here. Just to learn/understand how HTML/CSS works.

Comment: Please, for the love of all that's holy, do not use `* { margin / padding / etc. }` as a reset. That's going to be a gigantic assault on performance, because the asterisk targets every element on your page. You can read up on CSS Normalize or CSS Reset if you're inclined to use one (it's really not necessary but still commonly used).

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes Thanks for the tip! Again, I was just messing around so I wanted to be sure I had nothing altering my ideas with default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html has:

```
<div id="container 5">
```

It should be

```
<div id="container5">
```

Comment: I don't know what to say -.-' ... Thanks, it worked perfectly.

Comment: This would be a time when using `!important` would be helpful for debuging. It might help identify that the css rule is not targeting what you want. I am not advocating `!important` as an easy fix to your css / html problems, just a tool.

Comment: okay nice. I don't know what that is but I'll read up on it a bit later today.

Comment: Here is an [article](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) to help you out.